# Cloudfoundry setting JAVA_OPTS environment variable

Tags: java, cloud-foundry

I am deploying some application in cloudfoundry. I have some library jar and configuration files also inside the application. I want to setup those jar and config file as environment variable, so I did

```
cf set-env APP_NAME JAVA_OPTS "-Dconf=/location/library.jar"
```

After these changes, I have to restage the application and I am always getting **java.util.zip.ZipException**.

Comment: Did you check that you have correct path supplied to the library/conf files by ssh'ing into the container or downloading droplet?

Comment: Yes, I did check. What I am thinking is when we restage the application, it just deletes the app, so I am getting such exception.

Comment: I see... Did you try to set this environment variable via application manifest?

The application files should be available at the start stage per https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/how-applications-are-staged.html#stage-buildpack

 It also would be good to increase debug level by cf set-env <APP> JBP_LOG_LEVEL DEBUG  (per https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/debugging-the-buildpack.md)

Comment: I did setup like command above

Comment: Good. Any chance to provide a copy of app/.java-buildpack.log?

Comment: I got something like this. Server error, status code: 400, error code: 190001, message: File error: Request failed for app: APP_NAME, instance: 0 and path: APP_NAME/.java-buildpack.log as the instance is not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137511/discussion-between-amit-and-anatoly-kern).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error log from cloud foundry was not helpful. It was because some of the dependency was required by the jar and they were missing. After adding those dependencies inside the workspace solved the issue.